# How to change the image obtained from API every 2-3 seconds?

Tags: android

I want to change my Image (whose poster path is stored in a `List`) in an `Imageview` every 2 seconds, I tried to do so with a `Handler` and a thread but my application crashes.

Here is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    /** Calling this method for upcoming movies**/
    Call<HomePageRespons> callUpcoming=apiInterface.
                                        getUpcomingMovie(API_KEY);
    callUpcoming.enqueue(new Callback<HomePageRespons>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HomePageRespons> call, 
            Response<HomePageRespons> response) {
            int statusCode=response.code();
            int pos=0;
            final List<HomePage> list2=response.body().getResult();
            int totalresult=response.body().getTotalResult();
            Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+
            list2.get(pos).getPosterPath()).into(poster1);
            pos++;
            if(pos!=totalresult) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                            onStart();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HomePageRespons> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG,t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please add your LogCat of the crash.

Comment: First dont call onStart recursively. create your own method for image loading. Also you cannot update UI in another thread. You should use a Runnable with a Handler to update the UI. or use the activity mainUIThread to update the UI.

Comment: @FarooqArshed  thanks for your help, i used runOnUiThread() and now its working fine.